# Save canvas after pixel modification as image to further modification(change and flatten)

Tags: p5.js

So far i can manage to manipulate pixels on canvas but i would like to save it on bt click and display again on window and modificate more . This is my code for canvas pixels modification... If i want to flatten the image when i use  blendmode and manipulate colours of the rectangle its working. When i use pixels array and i press flatt it is not showing the colours at all please help...

flattten = createCanvas

[btn 1]press -

```
flatten.push();
flatten.image(canvas1,0,0);
flatten.pop();  

function draw (){
if flatt{
image(flatten,0,0);
}
}
```

Please help...

```
let d = pixelDensity();

loadPixels();

for (let i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < width; j++) {

        var index = 4*((d+j)*width*d+(d+i));

        var r =pixels[index+0];
        var g = pixels[index+1];
        var b = pixels[index+2];
        var a = pixels[index+3];

        var luma = r -valueH + g-valueS  + b;
        var luma1 = r  + g-valueH  + b -valueB;

        pixels[index+0] = luma;
        pixels[index+1] = luma1;
    }
}

if (mouseX <= width && mouseX >= 0 && mouseY <= height && mouseY >= 0) {
    if (mouseIsPressed) {
        valueH = map(mouseX, 0, width,30,180);
        valueS = map(mouseX, 0, height,0,180);
        valueB = map(mouseY, 0, height,30,180);
        valueA = map(mouseX, 0, height,1,1);
    }
}
updatePixels();
```

Comment: What have you tried and what doesn't work? If you look at p5js documentation you'll find [`saveCanvas()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/saveCanvas) which allows to save a canvas to an image file and [`createGraphics()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/createGraphics) which allows to draw in an offscreen buffer. All of the doc entries come with some examples of how to use the functions, you should probably experiment with these and update your question to specify what is causing you an issue in particular.

Comment: I know about createGraphics(), saveCanvas(), createImage(), but i can't create image to further manipulation...